# How do you deploy firebase cloud functions to all aliases?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have cloud functions set up for a project that will be used by multiple projects. I understand that you can deploy those functions to different projects using `firebase use` and adding/using aliases. Is there a way to deploy the functions to ***all*** known project aliases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built in to the Firebase CLI to do this as each project is considered to be a fully separate environment. You can use the `--project <alias_or_project_id>` flag to deploy to different aliases without having to switch using `firebase use`:

```
firebase deploy --project alias1
firebase deploy --project alias2
firebase deploy --project alias3
```

You could write a shell script to do all of those one after another or in parallel.

Comment: That's too bad. I wish it would deploy to all by default and selectively deploy by using `firebase use`. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase CLI doesn't have a command for that.  You can write a shell script or some other program to automate the execution of `firebase deploy` as many times as needed for each project you want to deploy.